# returning a 2D arrray in c++

Tags: c++

I recentley started coding in C++ and I can't seem to understand how to ruturn the 2d array

> GridArray

Is the problem somewhere in the type of the method because I can't seem to resolve it. Any help would be much appriciated!

```
static int GridArray [15][20];

int MapEditor::updateGrid(int *xCursor,int *yCursor){`
    int width=16;

    if(input.getInput()==psxUp){
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,255 );

        (*yCursor)--;
        if((*yCursor)<=0){
            (*yCursor)=15;
        }
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,224 );
    }
    if(input.getInput()==psxLeft){
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,255 );

        (*xCursor)--;
        if((*xCursor)<=0){
            (*xCursor)=20;
        }
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,224 );
    }

    if(input.getInput()==psxRight){
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,255 );

        (*xCursor)++;
        if((*xCursor)>=20){
            (*xCursor)=0;
        }
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,224 );
    }
    if(input.getInput()==psxDown){
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,255 );

        (*yCursor)++;
        if((*yCursor)>=15){
            (*yCursor)=0;
        }
        VGA.drawRect((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16,(*xCursor)*16+width,(*yCursor)*16+width,224 );
    }
    if(input.getInput()==psxSqu){
        spriteSelector.setSprite(bricks_destructive,bricks_destructive_palette);
        spriteSelector.drawAtPosition((*xCursor)*16,(*yCursor)*16);
        spriteSelector.update();
        GridArray[(*yCursor)][(*xCursor)]=1;
        Serial.println(GridArray[(*yCursor)][(*xCursor)]);
    }
    delay(120);
    if(input.getInput()==psxSlct){
        Serial.println(GridArray);
        return GridArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code meant for Arduino or any other Microcontroller? Microcontrollers usually only allow for a subset of the C++ language that's why it's somewhat relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you cannot return plain arrays (neither 1D ones nor 2D ones or higher). One could return a reference to such an array, and it would even be possible to encapsulate such arrays in a `struct`-object (which then could be returned). 
However, these solutions are probably a work around of what is actually intended.

As you start coding C++ you might start with abandoning "old fashioned C style" and make use of the C++ concepts like standard library and its containers, e.g. with `std::array`. With that, you' code above example differently:

```
#include <array>

typedef std::array<std::array<int,15>,20> GridArray;

GridArray initGrid() {
    GridArray ga = { { 0 } };
    ga[0][0] = 15;
    ga[0][1] = 30;
    return ga;
}

int main() {

    GridArray g = initGrid();
    for(auto row : g) {
        for (auto column : row) {
            cout << column << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that there are other variants as well (e.g. passing arrays in as input parameters to functions which then alter them rather then creating and returning them in the function. But actually I think that the `std::array`-approach comes closest to that what you need.

Comment: It's possible to return a reference to the array; see the other answer. Also, it's possible to return a "decayed" version — a pointer to a 1-D array. Encapsulating in a struct is not the only and not the best way to return a 2-D array.

Comment: Instead of returning the array one could also pass the grid as a parameter by ref `int (&grid)[15][20]`. It'd be better to use a standard container but I'm fairly sure OP is using a limited subset of C++.

@anatolyg Of course, it's always possible to return pointers. It's not really beautiful either but I guess in OP's case it's viable since he's hard coding everything anyways.

Comment: @anatolyg: right, the encapsulation thing is just a clumsy workaround (though possible); I removed it because it is misleading. Concerning returning references to plain arrays: I think these are a clumsy workaround, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting compile errors?
You have 2 problems:

1. The return type of your function is `int` but you are trying to return `int
   [15][20]`
2. You aren't allowed to return an array from a function
3. Not all code paths return a value, your `return GridArray` needs to be outside the if statement.

you probably want something like this:

```
typedef int ArrayType[15][20];
static ArrayType GridArray;

ArrayType& f()
{
    ...
    return GridArray;
}
```

Or even better use std::vector or std::array

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, and it gets overlooked for more "technical" solutions, but this solution is rather simple.

This solution doesn't require intimate knowledge of pointers or references, doesn't require knowledge or usage of STL, doesn't require features or libraries that exist in standard C++ that may not exist on some platforms, should be very lightweight, and should be easily understandable by even beginner C++ programmers.  However there is some code you would need to change to apply this technique.

The solution is this: simply wrap the 2-dimensional array inside a `struct` and pass / return the `struct`.  That's it.

Since a `struct` is copyable and assignable (and arrays are neither one), then it is simply a matter of wrapping the array inside a struct and use that as a poor-man's container (even though it just works).  Copies work, assignments work, passing to and from functions work, etc.

```
struct Array2D
{
   int GridArray [15][20];
};
```

Then you simply pass and return `Array2D`'s around.  No pointers are necessary.

```
static Array2D theGrid;

Array2D& SomeFunction()
{
   ...
    theGrid.GridArray[(*yCursor)][(*xCursor)]=1;
    return theGrid;
}
```

The above returns a reference to the `Array2D` that was declared static.  But you also get a choice of returning a copy of the results is so desired.

```
Array2D SomeFunction2()
{
   ...
    theGrid.GridArray[(*yCursor)][(*xCursor)]=1;
    return theGrid;
}
```

The above takes the `static Array2D` that was declared and returns a copy of it.

You then have the power to do things like:

```
Array2D tempGrid = theGrid;   // get a copy of the original
//..
tempGrid.GridArray[0][0] = 1; // changes the copy but not the original
```

No need for `for` loops or `memcpy`'s to assign one array to the other -- let the `struct` do that work automatically and easily for you since assignment and copy is built-in with structs and classes.

But again please note that you will need to change some code around to append `xyz.` to your current code that refers to `GridArray`, where `xyz` is the name of the `Array2D` instance.