# Why does a two-dimensional array become a one-dimensional array after passing it to a function?（C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a simple Snake game. When making a map, my definition of the map is as follows

```
int map[25][25] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)//Set the boundary to - 2
{
    map[0][i] = -2;
    map[24][i] = -2;
}
for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++)//Set the boundary to - 2
{
    map[i][0] = -2;
    map[i][24] = -2;
}
```

Then I made a function to simulate the motion of the snake。（The first parameter is the class I created: snake，The second is its moving direction. The key is the third parameter, the map array I put in.）

```
void snake_move(Snake snake1, int direction, int map[][25])
```

Then I made a call to the function.（The third parameter is the two-dimensional array pointer I passed in）

```
snake_move(snake1, direction, map);
```

Then the following figure appears
[image]

**I found that it was a two-dimensional array before the function call，which is as follows**
[image]

Why does this happen and how to solve this problem? I look forward to your reply・ｖ・

Comment: Function arguments don't work with arrays the way you might expect. Instead, they pretend to work with arrays but really just use a pointer to the first element of the array. In this case, a pointer to the first row. The rest of the array is still there, but in `snake_move` the actual size is not known so the debugger can only show you the first line. This is a very unfortunate inheritance from C. Consider using `std::array` instead which is just as good as a C array but doesn't have any of the quirks associated with them.

Comment: First, I wouldn't name the variable `map`, as there is a `std::map` that exists in C++.  Try `using Map = std::array<std::array<int,25>,25>;` and declare/pass `Map` types around instead of dumb 2D arrays.

Comment: You could also use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341472/returning-a-2d-arrray-in-c/49342542#49342542) and adapt it to passing 2D arrays (the answer refers to returning them, but it is basically the same issue).

Comment: you can see it still recognize `int[25]*`, I'd say it just a bug when present the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I haven't learned much about array before， I'll go to learn it now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: The whole point of namespaces is that you CAN have `map` as a name, without clashes. That's why we tell people to avoid `using namespace std` at global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass built-in arrays like this to functions. `snake_move()`, even though it appears to have an argument that looks like a 2D array, it actually takes a pointer to a 1D array. This:

```
void func(int map[][25]);
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
void func(int (*map)[25]);
```

`map` is a pointer to an array of 25 `int` elements. When you call that function:

```
func(map);
```

The `map` array "decays" to a pointer that points to its first element.

This is an unfortunate consequence of C++'s compatibility with C.

To avoid issues like this, use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (for fixed-size, static allocation of elements), or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (for dynamically allocated elements.)

To get a 2D array, you need to use an array of arrays or a vector of vectors. For an array, that means:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 25>, 25>
```

This means "an array containing 25 arrays of 25 `int` elements.

It's a good idea to make `snake_move` take a `const` reference to avoid an unnecessary copy of the whole array. So:

```
#include <array>

void snake_move(
    Snake snake1, int direction,
    const std::array<std::array<int, 25>, 25>& map);

// ...

std::array<std::array<int, 25>, 25> map{};

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    map[0][i] = -2;
    map[24][i] = -2;
}

for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
    map[i][0] = -2;
    map[i][24] = -2;
}

snake_move(snake1, direction, map);
```

If `snake_move()` needs to modify the passed array, then remove the `const`.

To reduce the need to write the type over and over again, you can use an alias (with the `using` keyword):

```
using MapType = std::array<std::array<int, 25>, 25>;

void snake_move(Snake snake1, int direction, const MapType& map);

// ...

MapType map{};
// ...
```

The `{}` in the `map` declaration will initialize all values to zero. You can also use:

```
MapType map = {};
```

which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen

Because of **type decay**. In particular, in many contexts (including when appearing as a parameter to a function), an array **decays** to a *pointer to its first element*. For example:

1. The type `int [6]` decays to `int*`
2. The type `int *[6]` decays to `int**`.
3. The type `double [10]` decays to `double*`.
4. The type `int [5][6]` decays to `int (*)[6]`.

Thus, in you example, the third parameter `int map[][25]` is actually a pointer to an array of size `25` with elements of type `int`, ie `int (*)[25]`.

---

> how to solve this problem?

You can use `std::array`, as shown below:

```cpp
void snake_move(Snake snake1, int direction, 
//----------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------->std::array used
                              std::array<std::array<int, 25>,25> map) 
{
    
}

std::array<std::array<int, 25>,25> map; //sta::array used
```

If the function `snake_move()` doesn't change the passed `std::array`, and to avoid unnecessary copying, you can take the `std::array` as a reference to `const`:

```cpp
void snake_move(Snake snake1, int direction, 
                              const std::array<std::array<int, 25>,25>& map)
//----------------------------^^^^^-----------------------------------^----->lvalue reference to non-const std::array<std::array<int, 25>,25> 
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually keep the dimension without using `std::array`

```
void snake_move(Snake snake1, int direction, int (&map)[25][25]);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EYz7hzjTj

---

Also note it's **not** a 1D array (i.e. `map[0]` is not `-2`), the debug window **does** recognize and shows it's a `int[25]*`, it probably just have some bug that fail to display it in the correct format.

Comment: I don't think `int[25]*` is valid C++.

Comment: @Albert you cannot write it that way, but I think it's meaning is unambiguous. i.e. `int(*)[25]`, pointer to `int[25]`

Comment: No, `int (*)[25]` is actually a valid type in C++ while `int[25]*` is not. It's meaning may be unambiguous to you.

Comment: @Albert unambiguous  or not, it's not my point anyway, The editor does recognize the type and it a bug that it's doesn't format it correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is a bug that it doesn't display/recognize the type correctly.

Comment: @Albert yes, I just want to point out is is not 1D array as OP and other answer seems to suggest. well, it seems I failed to deliver that.